# Angular mat-date-picker change months from capital to lowercase (JAN to Jan)

Tags: html, angular, typescript

As in the question, I'm trying to to edit my datepicker so that the months are displayed in the following format: Jan, Feb, Mar, Apr instead of JAN, FEB, etc...

I tried playing around with the moment.js formats but there doesn't seem to be anything that does exactly what I want.

Currently formatting it as follows:

```
export const MY_FORMATS = {
       parse: {
          dateInput: 'MM/YYYY',
       },
       display: {
          dateInput: 'MMM YYYY',
          monthYearLabel: 'MMM YYYY',
          dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
          monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM YYYY',
          },
};
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! - please show what you have tried

Answer (score 0):

don't know it might be helpful but did you try to write **yyyy** instead of **YYYY**?

```
export const MY_FORMATS = {
       parse: {
          dateInput: 'MM/yyyy',
       },
       display: {
          dateInput: 'MMM yyyy',
          monthYearLabel: 'MMM yyyy',
          dateA11yLabel: 'LL',
          monthYearA11yLabel: 'MMMM yyyy',
          },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get it only with .css

In styles.css

```
.mat-calendar-header button.mat-calendar-period-button {
  text-transform: lowercase;
}
.mat-calendar-header button.mat-calendar-period-button span:first-letter {
   text-transform: uppercase
}
```